# errno: 1251, sqlMessage: 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, mysql-workbench

I'm creating the simple api project in nodejs.

For that I have installed mySql workbench with version 8.0.11.
I have created config file, dbConnection.js file and in the dbconnection.js file I have written the following code :

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var path = require('path');
var config = require(path.resolve('./', 'config'))

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: config.databaseHost,
    user: config.databaseUser,
    password: config.databasePassword,
    database: config.databaseDatabaseName,
    multipleStatements: true
});

connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error connecting to Database',err);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Connection established');
});
module.exports = connection;
```

And I'm facing following error :

> code: 'ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE',
> errno: 1251,
> sqlMessage: 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client',
> sqlState: '08004',
> fatal: true

Note : I kept my congif as simple as it can be, user = root , password = root, host = localhost.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Open terminal and login:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

(then type your password)

After that:

```
USE mysql;

UPDATE user SET authentication_string=password(''), plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE user='root';
```

And the last important thing is to reset mysql service:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Comment: When pasting in the UPDATE command I get the error: 1604 that there is an error with the syntax

Answer (score 25):

once you establish your host, root, password &, etc inside your MySQL connection function.. paste the following inside of your database you are trying to connect within workbench with the following:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your_current_password';
```

Go back to the terminal and run node `<file name.js>` again

Comment: This solution is the quickest and easiest way to solve the issue

Comment: Had absolutely no luck with this method. Same error continued to come up. I tried several other methods like creating a totally new user as well but the only thing that worked was using mysql2 as the library.

Comment: Change the password value

Answer (score 16):

Install mysql2 instead of mysql

```
npm install mysql2
```

Then add this to  index.js

```
const mysql = require('mysql2')
```

Answer (score 8):

You have to reconfigure MySQL Server. for that follow these steps.

**1)** Open **mysql intsaller**.

**2)** Click on **Reconfigure** (to the left mysql server)

**3)** Go to **Authentication method tab** (by clicking on **Next** twice.)

**4)** Then select the radio button **Use Legacy Authentication Method**. Click Next.

**5)** Enter your password. Click on Check. Go to **Apply Configuration** (by clicking on Next twice).

**6)** Click on **Execute**. Then Finish.

That's it. Enjoy Hacking!!

Answer (score 6):

Was getting ERROR 1251 in node v17 with mysql

```
❌ // didn't worked: errno 1251 ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE

import mysql from 'mysql';
```

Try to remove `mysql` from node and replace it for `mysql2`

```
yarn remove 'mysql'
```

```
yarn add 'mysql2'
```

```
✅  import mysql2 from 'mysql2';
```

This fixed the issue for me!

Answer (score 5):

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'current password';
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. It did not work for the root user. I created a new user (using mySQL workbench) and gave privileges to the new user. Then I tried with the new user and it worked fine. [see workbench settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rO5D.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `mysql`

```
yarn remove mysql
yarn add mysql2
import mysql2 from "mysql2"
```

This fixed issue for me.
code
:

> "ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE"
> errno
> :
> 1251
> fatal
> :
> true
> sqlMessage
> :
> "Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client"
> sqlState
> :
> "08004"

Comment: Please format your code properly using `backticks`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with your password and user name root if your password was not root try with your password.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I did not want to manipulate my "root" user because I'm using it in my Java applications, so that I decided to create a new User for NodeJS stuff.

I'm using MySQL 8.0.31, and Node's MySQL version "2.18.1"
This solution really solved my problem:

first, log in to the MySQL server using root access:

```
mysql -u <MYSQL_USER> -p <MYSQL_PASSWORD>
```

once you entered mysql shell, run these commands:

```
create user '<YOUR_USERNAME>'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH 'mysql_native_password' BY '<YOUR_PASSWORD>';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.Copy the code below**

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'current password'
```

**2.Paste in the Table you want to connect**

**3.Run the thunder icon**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because in your mysql2 version is outdated please update it to current LTS.
I was also facing same issue then I just delete my node_modules file and package-lock.json file and change the version of my mysql2 version to current LTS version in my package.json file and again install all my files by running command npm install.